# ng-srcset images initially not displaying in IE11 intermittently

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11, srcset, picturefill

The page loads without any of the images displaying on IE11 only, but refreshes them accordingly when we resize the browser intermittently (1/3 loads). We cannot replicate this with any of the other browsers. srcset works fine by itself with static content.

**[Here is a Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ukf1FBcZgCRll9Wd7PHi?p=preview)** of it not working in IE11.

Or quick and easy, the actual img html we're using:

```
<img data-ng-srcset="{{::image.url}}, {{::image.url2x}}" alt="{{::image.name}}"/>
```

The images or surrounding divs do **not** have any transitions, shadows or opacity applied.

The html renders fine with angular passing over and rewriting the srcset attribute correctly. The images just do not appear, only the alt tag. Wondering if this could be a call stack issue due to the intermittence of it, maybe a race condition with Picturefill loading before angular finishes a digest or something.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: IE developer sites says, they support img srcset only for IE edge , link here : https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/imgsrcset/

Comment: Sorry, we're using picturefill too, I'll update question so it's more explicit. Picturefill adds in src for those browsers not supporting srcset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across this as a solution: http://tech.endeepak.com/blog/2014/05/03/waiting-for-angularjs-digest-cycle/

```
var waitForRenderAndDoSomething = function() {
    if($http.pendingRequests.length > 0) {
        $timeout(waitForRenderAndDoSomething); // Wait for all templates to be loaded
    } else {
        $window.picturefill();
    }
}

$timeout(waitForRenderAndDoSomething);
```

The only issue that the blog post describes is here, so if anyone has anything better please let me know:

> The $http.pendingRequests supposed to be used for debugging purpose only. If angular team decides to remove this, you can implement the same using http interceptors as suggested in this link.

Answer (score 1):

A work around if you use PictureFill in a loop and in a specific case (not on all images of your application), is calling a function that launch PictureFill directly from HTML, after last item loaded (**this is not the best practice but fix the IE11 problem**) :

```
<picture><!-- Your image --></picture>
<span ng-if="$last">
    {{ controllerAlias.launchPictureFill() }}
</span>
```